# Free online UK maps

Tags: uk, maps

Can I view OS maps for the UK online for free?

I want to see both the Landranger and Explorer maps if possible.

Comment: You can get the OS map app as well which allows you to see maps and some free routes.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Aravona I think you have to pay for the maps with the app, also I have had issues with that app, it's not very good.

Comment: @Gabriel Hey, it's about maps, I posted it here so people know about it.  I don't use the OpenData group, if you want to post it there feel free.

Comment: @MJH - you can view where you are currently for free at any time, if you want to download maps and do most routes you need to have premium/buy the maps yes. The Free version won't track you but handy to open and see whats around you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, go to https://www.bing.com/maps/ and select "Ordnance Survey" in the drop-down in the top right corner.

The zoom level you select will show either the 1:50,000 or 1:25,000 map you will see.

Comment: AFAIK, this only works from inside the UK, doesn't it?

Comment: @phg Not sure TBH, that would make sense though.

Comment: @phg I just tried it out; you're correct. From Germany, I don't see the "Ordnance Survey" option unless I browse via a UK proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Ordnance Survey Maps can be download to a mobile device for free using Avenza PDF Maps.  The maps can be viewed without an internet or cellular connection after download.  Avenza allows you to store up to 5 maps for free so you can either download them and swap them out or pay for a professional version of the app.
https://www.avenzamaps.com/maps/search.html?query=&location_mode=map_input&location=&sort=relevance&price_max=1&page=0&debug=&current_map_id=&location_box=55.0150538046944%2C-1.5198503796983687%2C54.02605303562811%2C-2.7654253308702437&vendor_ids=&category_ids=&merge_mode=v4&debug_ids=